# How do you use enzyme to test application flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom

I want to write an integration test that checks if you're on the login page and you login with the correct credentials, you are redirected to the user's dashboard page.  We will mock out our backend in this test, but I'd like to use as much of the real front end code as possible.

I've been googling this for a while and have not been able to find any examples of how to do this.  Most examples either test to make sure routes are there or but never actually go through the actual flow.  e.g., https://medium.com/@antonybudianto/react-router-testing-with-jest-and-enzyme-17294fefd303

We're using the latest version of react-router-dom and jest for the test.

Comment: something like https://www.cypress.io/ might help. This will actually open a browser window for you and run through the operations you tell it. It has it's own assertion api, so not sure how to use within your existing testing setup, but worth a look?

Comment: @ChaimFriedman we'd like to avoid browser tests if we can get around it because it's a lot easier to mock out a backend if the test and the code is running in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is too wide, [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) is oriented to components testing so you need to split your test to a more component-specific definition
I think that [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) could more useful for your type of testing

Comment: Are you saying I can't do this with Enzyme, or it's not meant to do it?  If it can't be done with enzyme, I'd like to know why (or at least have a link to learn why)

Comment: no it's just, that the way you describe the test, I would advise using a solution like puppeteer. you can still do it with Enzyme by mounting the highest component needed for your use case or test every component that is used in it